# C# dispose is not called when object leaves scope in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, destructor, raii, finalizer

I have a C# object that is resposible for a ressource which looks like this:

```
  public sealed class CLoadingScope
  {
    private bool isDisposed;

    public CLoadingScope()
    {}

    ~CLoadingScope()
    {
      // must be disposed otherwise it is used incorrectly
      if (!isDisposed)
      {
        throw new ApplicationException("RAII object has not been disposed");
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      // CLEANUP CODE HERE […]
      isDisposed = true;
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
  };
```

I am using this in some C++/CLI code like this:

```
{
  CLoadingScope scope;
  // CODE THAT USES THE RESSOURCE HERE […]
}
```

But this results in the Exception being thrown.
I was expecting this to work because Dispose is the destructor of C# classes and stack objects are destroyed at the end of their scope. At least that's how I interpreted the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338950/what-is-the-managed-c-equivalent-to-the-c-sharp-using-statement).
With all the naming and usage confusion of finalizers and destructors in C#, C++ and C++/CLI I assume I mixed up something. Can anybody tell me what? :)

Comment: Implement IDisposable interface + use using(var a = new CLoadingScope()) that will call destructor...

Comment: @Sergejs I don't think using directives are allowed in C++/CLI.

Comment: hmm, sorry. This is how it works in C#. Then, I believe you have to call destructor manually.

Comment: For a deeper understanding of when dispose is called read this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871888/dispose-when-is-it-called and for what may be more of a definitive answer for you read this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987251/manually-destroy-c-sharp-objects

Comment: Furthermore when an object is disposed of it is only queued for GC, which will happen 'later'

Comment: @PaulZahra I understand what to do in C# but in C++/CLI I cannot use using directives and Dispose is not called when the object goes out of scope. I simply don't see how to do RAII in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have authored this class in C#, and are using it from C++/CLI.

You are correct that C++/CLI will automatically call `Dispose` for you--but that's only if the class you are dealing with implements `IDisposable`.  In your case, your class does not implement `IDisposable`, and thus, `Dispose` in this case is just a normal method.

Change your class as follows:

```
public sealed class CLoadingScope : IDisposable
```

Comment: The C# class had been written by another dev and I simply missed that the interface inheritance was missing. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

Add a destructor which will make c++ /cli automagically inherit IDisposable.

Then cast to IDisposable to access the Dispose method

```
((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
```

P.S. With regards to C# Dispose() is called with a using statement or of course manually, otherwise it doesn't get called automatically, not sure why the using equivalent in C++/CLI isn't calling Dispose()

Comment: Calling it explicitly somewhat defeats the purpose of RAII of making it work in the presence of exceptions. :/