# How to destroy an object in C#?

Tags: object, dll

I am using a DLL that is being used in VB6 and the object is destroyed with
oDPID = nothing
I'm doing this in C# and I do get results expect ..

```
fun()
{
    var oDPID = new DPID.Generator();
    Call oDPID.DoThis();
}
```

If you run this code a number of times without destroying the object, I'll have memory problem
How do I destroy the Object when I'm done with it?

Comment: You don't. Garbage collector does it. More information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987251/manually-destroy-c-sharp-objects

Comment: Not the Case....... running that after n number of times hogs the system.

Comment: Is this an unmanaged object? Does it implement IDisposable?

Comment: I think it is . After typing dot next to the object it only provides me a list of Append , Equals,Get,GetTYpe and ToString no destructors coming up.